# How to check if page is already being viewed

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

In my Xamarin.Forms app, I want to make sure `MyPage` is not already being viewed before pushing it on the stack:

```
if (App.Current.MainNavigation.NavigationStack?.Any(x => x is MyPage) == true ||
    App.Current.MainNavigation.ModalStack?.Any(x => x is MyPage) == true)
   {
       return;
   }
   else
   {
       await App.Current.MainNavigation.PushModalAsync(new MyPage());
   }
```

But it is not finding `MyPage` on either stack and is calling `PushModalAsync` twice.

Comment: Question is: where do you put these bits

Comment: In my own custom class

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't reproduce your problem for the code is not completed. But if you want to  check if page is already being viewed. You can override the OnAppearing method that will be called when a page be viewed. Such as:

```
    public partial class MyPage : ContentPage
    {
        public static bool flag = false;
        public MyPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        protected override void OnAppearing()
        {
            base.OnAppearing();
            flag = true;
        }
    }
```

And then detect it by the following code:

```
   if(MyPage.flag = true)
   {
       return;
   }
   else
   {
       await App.Current.MainNavigation.PushModalAsync(new MyPage());
   }
```